# Microsoft Reporting Services Projects Visual Studio 2017 Extension 2.0 Downgrade to 1.24

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, report

Recently Microsoft released version 2.0 of their [Microsoft Reporting Services Projects Visual Studio 2017 Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio) which vastly changed the query designer so that it completely breaks older reports as those reports don't work in the non-visual, visual query designer (and/or need to be redesigned). This is completely unreasonable to use if someone has literally 1,000+ reports to now re-create for no real reason or added value.

Is there anyway to get version 1.24 which is compatible? Or is there anyway to downgrade the extension to the previous version (1.24)? Is there an official e-mail or way to contact Microsoft directly about this?

Thanks for any help on this.

Edit: Screenshots

Before (it would look close to):

[image]

New (it is this...which is really not ideal, for obvious reasons):

[image]

Comment: A couple of things: This is probably not the right place to ask this so you may find people vote to close this question. However, I'm not sure what you mean by the non-visual, visual query designer? What type of datasets do you have, plain SQL, SSAS/MDX? I've written some very complex stuff and never had a problem with upgrading extensions, I always "edit as text", but maybe I'm missing something. Can you post screen shots of where you have the issue?

Comment: @AlanSchofield They're SQL queries that would normally use the visual query designer that get once you right click on a dataset. In 2.0 they change the query designer so that has no visual elements or SQL pane. We often use the visual pane to see the relationship between tables and complex joins as well as the SQL pane to do some fine-grained tweaking of the queries. I (will) have edited screenshots into the OP.

Comment: Found another post with a little more detail.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52611118/ssrs-query-designer-changed-in-visual-studio-2017

Comment: it would appear your only option would be to create queries in SSMS, using it's visual designer and paste into your dataset. I've done it this way for years as the visual designers produce very verbose SQL so that's why I hadn't noticed.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Not being trying to be mean, but that's kind of ridiculous (especially if I have to edit a complex query whereby now I have to use SSMS, remove parameters, and do some trickery). Isn't there a way to downgrade an extension or download a previous version? I would think there must be a way in case a bug or regression is introduced in the latest version of an extension. I have 1.13 from when I first installed the extension, is there a way to incrementally update it? I think I have a system restore point where the old extension might live, is there a way to find its files to use it?

Comment: I was simply pointing out why I had not noticed the issue as I'm not a fan of visual designers so I never use them. I'm not sure if/how you'll be able to rollback to a previous version, sorry.

Comment: Oh no no. I meant having to use SSMS as a temporary (hopefully) solution being kind of annoying if that is what Microsoft is ok with having users do. I was expressing my frustration at Microsoft, more or less, at why this is not an efficient workflow for developers and for not offering an "opt-out" to the new designer. I use 'Edit Text" more frequently, but some queries just do so many joins and each is intricately complex that seeing it visually can help a lot (as well seeing the columns per table).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anybody reads this via future searching (and for the other person who posted having an issue with this), the way this can be fixed is much easier than expected. The answer is to follow a relatively simple procedure:

1. Backup any important files, solutions, projects, etc. as your mileage may vary with this process
2. Uninstall the Microsoft Reporting Services Project Extension from Visual Studio 2017 (Tools -> Extensions & Updates) [You'll need Admin privileges for this]
3. Close All Visual Studio instances
4. Download 15.8.0 (or whatever version you'd prefer, 15.8.0 has the SSRS extension version of 1.24) from Microsoft's SSDT previous versions page: [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Previous Versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi?view=sql-server-2017).
5. Install the aforementioned downloaded version and select Visual Studio 2017 for the instance and then just Reporting Services for the packages (The first option is ALWAYS selected so there is nothing you could do to avoid it, I don't think).
6. Once the install completes, open Visual Studio 2017 as Administrator (This is indeed different from normally opening it, even as an admin on the PC)
7. Go to the Extensions & Updates section (again, Tools -> Extensions & Updates) and disable "Automatically update this extension" via the right-hand detail pane. You can also verify you have version 1.24 here as well.

That should be it and you should be good to go at that point. Only caveat is that you may need to "clean" any Reporting Services projects via Clean Solution (I had to at least).

As always, your mileage may vary and you should ALWAYS do backups of your PC/files (and/or create a restore point) in the event something goes pear shaped or is incompatible.

Best of luck everyone and I hope Microsoft reverses forcing this new "simplified" (essentially useless) interface onto the visual query designer.

Comment: Indeed, this solved it just fine for me.  My thanks to you @B1313.