# SSRS Query Designer Changed in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

I have a problem that started Monday (10/1/18) where the query designer for report projects (*.rptproj) has changed, I believe to the Report Builder Visual Designer.  This has the unfortunate effect of me having to use the Text-Based Designer for managing the dataset query in the report, which is less than optimal.

When I try to change out of the Text-Based Designer, I get this message:

[image]

This happens for all our reports in our Reporting project.  Has anyone else run into this issue?  All of my Google-Fu attempts to find a solution have failed.

From what I can tell, the Microsoft Reporting Services Projects extension in VS was updated on 9/28/18, but I don't see anything in the change log for such a change.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: somebody asked about this earlier, now his post makes more sense.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609228/microsoft-reporting-services-projects-visual-studio-2017-extension-2-0-downgrade

Comment: Thanks for the link Alan.  My main issue with Microsoft on this issue is that they provided no option for existing reports for transition... basically use the text editor or manually convert the report for use in the visual designer.  Sure, I can transfer the query back/forth between SSMS but that's not an ideal workflow.

Comment: @ricke Please see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609228/microsoft-reporting-services-projects-visual-studio-2017-extension-2-0-downgrade) for the answer to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @B1313, his answer to his question has done the trick for me.

[Microsoft Reporting Services Projects Visual Studio 2017 Extension 2.0 Downgrade to 1.24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609228/microsoft-reporting-services-projects-visual-studio-2017-extension-2-0-downgrade)