# Query Designer screen of SSRS Report has only two tools (Edit as text and Import)

Tags: reporting-services

I am learning SSRS report by using SQL Server 2017 enterprise and Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise. When I create a new report by using wizard. I only see two tools on the menu bar (please see the picture 1). How can I show other tools like picture 2.

#### Picture 1

[image: Picture 1]

#### Picture 2

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: To use the design editor follow the link below: [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609228/microsoft-reporting-services-projects-visual-studio-2017-extension-2-0-downgrade/52636524#52636524)

Comment: Thanks Aduguid, It's very helpful to me! <3